# xtable, changing column titles and adding a title

Tags: r, xtable

I am trying to add a title to this xtable

```
DATA5$Predict=predict(best.mod,newx=y2, type="class")
DATA5$armedornot2=ifelse(DATA5$armedornot!=1,"Yes","No")
DATA5$Predict=ifelse(DATA5$Predict <0.5, "No","Yes")
armedtable <- table(DATA5[,c("armedornot2","Predict")]) 
newtable<-cbind(armedtable,c(0,0))
xtable(newtable, caption=c("This is the title"), type="html", caption.placement="top")
```

However, this isn't working. I am also trying to change the V2 below to "No"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To change `V2` to `No`, change `cbind(armedtable,c(0,0))` to `cbind(armedtable, No = c(0,0))`

As for your caption, the issue is the printing. `xtable` itself doesn't take a `type` argument, it's `print.xtable` that determines the type (and the `caption.placement`). Try this:

```
print(xtable(newtable, caption=c("This is the title")),
      type="html", caption.placement="top")
```

Comment: I'm trying to knit to html, and it wont show up correctly if i use print. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue. Did you set your chunk option to `results = "asis"`? Maybe make a reproducible example?

Comment: When i put that in the chunk, it doesn't come out right. It comes out like this: % latex table generated in R 3.6.1 by xtable 1.8-4 package % Mon Dec 2 18:31:31 2019.

Comment: Are you using the `type = "html"` argument, in the `print` not in the `xtable`, as in my code? It sounds like you're not... If I run `print(xtable(head(mtcars), caption = "Title here"), type = "html", caption.placement = "top")` it starts with `<!-- html table generated in R...`. If you're seeing `% latex table` that means your `type` argument has a typo or is in the wrong place.